# How to use the new DayNight Theme?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-theme

Starting to get my hands into that new update to the Google Support Library and I want to implement the `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` into my app.
The problem I am having is that it seems no one explained how to customize it. So If I want to have a different `colorAccent` for day and a different one for night, how do I do that? Are you supposed to specify different dark and light themes to base off of? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the  [night resource qualifier folder](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#NightQualifier).
In this way you can define colors and the other resources for the **dark** (night)  and for the **light** theme (day).

**Qualifiers:**
`night`: Night time
`notnight`: Day time

In order to support the dark theme with a **Material Components Theme** use:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

With an **AppCompat** theme:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
   </style>
```

Then define in your app theme the references color resources, and **override** the value in the `values-night` directory if needed:

Example: `res\values\colors.xml`:

```
   <color name="colorPrimary">.....</color>
```

In `res\values-night\colors.xml` folders define the same color:

```
   <color name="colorPrimary">.....</color>
```

Comment: Ok, trying to set this up but I am having an issue. Even when I set the night mode to on, the theme still shows as light. Do I have to manually create the dark mode?

Comment: @JoeSmith Take a look here: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94#.eyx8h9u26

Comment: @JoeSmith You can also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640951/appcompat-daynight-theme-always-appears-as-a-light-theme

Comment: In my app, I've tried with `uiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` and it works perfectly on my Nexus 5 with Android 6 on an emulator with Android 6, but it doesn't work on emulator with Android 5.0.. Why?

Comment: What if i need to have a drawable selector? Do I have to create drawable-night and drawable-notnight respectively?

Comment: @ThanosF yes. for example: **drawable-night-hdpi** (night must go before resolution)